# Subnet or Not with 20 mask?

Tags: networking, routing, gateway

In a client warehouse,I'm installing a Pick to Light system but I'm having connection issues
between the server and the P2L controller. sometimes they communicate, sometimes they are not.

Their IT use IP from 192.168.1.x and 192.168.2.x with /20 subnet mask.
I noticed that in both 1.x and 2.x ip pools they use the same gateway which in fact is 192.168.1.1. Their server has ip 192.168.1.50 and they gave me 192.168.2.200 for my P2L Controller.

My questions are:

1. can 192.168.2.x and 192.168.1.x communicate directly without using the gateway because of the 20 mask?
2. can 192.168.2.x network use the 192.168.1.1 gateway because of the 20 mask?
3. is this practice relliable or it is mandatory every "subnet" to have its own gateway regardless of the subnet mask?

Thanks

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "every subnet" in question 3?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

1. Yes. If the subnet mask is smaller than 255.255.252.0 (CIDR /22) all devices with IP addresses 192.168.1.x and 192.168.2.x belong to the same subnet and don't need a router to communicate with each other.
2. Yes. With /20 mask (255.255.240.0) addresses in the range 192.168.0.1 - 192.168.15.254 form one subnet, and can use the same default gateway, whose IP must be in the same range; in this case it's 192.168.1.1.
3. Yes. Gateway router's job is to forward traffic into and out of the subnet. Without one traffic can only flow within the subnet. Consequently the GW must have an IP interface within the same range, and another IP interface on a different subnet. You can basically think of a subnet as a house, and gateway as the front door - one can hardly leave their house using the neighbor's front door :-)

---

HERE BE DRAGONS - subnet masks, network prefixes and binaries

---

Since Ye Olden Days subnets have been defined with a subnet mask. The most commonly known is 255.255.255.0. [CIDR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classless_Inter-Domain_Routing) notation is a different method of assigning IP addresses. With CIDR we don't talk about subnet masks, but network prefixes.

IPv4 address format is X.X.X.X. Each X is a [binary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_code) number of 8 digits, i.e. an octet, the dot `(.)` is the delimiter between fields. The maximum value that can be presented with 8 bits is 255, so the string with smallest values is 0.0.0.0, the string with largest values 255.255.255.255. Every IPv4 address sits somewhere in this range.

Presented in binary these are:

```
00000000 . 00000000 . 00000000 . 00000000 = 0.0.0.0
11111111 . 11111111 . 11111111 . 11111111 = 255.255.255.255
```

The most common network in the world is 192.168.1.0 with prefix of /24. Every home router by default uses this range. The available host IP address range is

```
11000000 . 10101000 . 00000001 . 00000001 = 192.168.1.1
11000000 . 10101000 . 00000001 . 11111110 = 192.168.1.254
```

The subnet mask of /24 prefix is

```
11111111 . 11111111 . 11111111 . 00000000 = 255.255.255.0
```

Note that the first and the last addresses in the range cannot be assigned to hosts, as the first is the network address (in this case 192.168.0.0/24), the last is the broadcast address (in this case 192.168.1.255/24).

In CIDR notation the most significant digits are the network prefix, the least significant digits form the host identifier. The number of digits in the network identifier is the network prefix. IP *192.168.1.100*/**24** is thus (**bolded** = network prefix, *italics* = host ID):

**11000000** . **10101000** . **00000001** . *01100100*

The network prefix contains 24 bits, hence notation /24. There are max 254 individual usable *hosts*, all of which can communicate directly with each other.

If we need a larger network for more *hosts*, we choose a smaller prefix; i.e. use less digits to represent the network:

**11000000** . **10101000** . **0000000** *1* . *01100100* = *192.168.1.100*/**23**

This host can communicate directly with host *192.168.0.100*/**23**:

**11000000** . **10101000** . **0000000** *0* . *01100100*

The usable *host* IPs in the entire subnet are

From: **11000000** . **10101000** . **0000000** *0* . *00000001* = *192.168.0.1*/**23**

To: **11000000** . **10101000** . **0000000** *1* . *11111110* = *192.168.1.254*/**23**

The subnet mask is

```
11111111 . 11111111 . 11111110 . 00000000 = 255.255.254.0
```

As long as the **network prefix** does not change, the *hosts* belong to the same subnet and can communicate directly without a router.

If we need a larger network still, we choose again a smaller **network prefix**:

**11000000** . **10101000** . **000000** *01* . *01100100* = *192.168.1.100*/**22**

... which gives us subnet mask

```
11111111 . 11111111 . 11111100 . 00000000 = 255.255.252.0
```

When the network prefix is /20, the 20 most significant bits are used for the **network prefix**. 12 least significant bits are *host identifiers*. So the entire range of usable hosts in the same subnet is:

From: **11000000** . **10101000** . **0000** *0000* . *00000001* = *192.168.0.1*/**20**

To: **11000000** . **10101000** . **0000** *1111* . *11111110* = *192.168.15.254*/**20**

... which gives us subnet mask

```
11111111 . 11111111 . 11110000 . 00000000 = 255.255.240.0
```

The network address is 192.168.1.0/20, the broadcast address 192.168.15.255/20.

Translating the IP addresses from the question:

**11000000** . **10101000** . **0000** *0001* . *00000001* = *192.168.1.1*/**20**

**11000000** . **10101000** . **0000** *0001*. *00110010* = *192.168.1.50*/**20**

**11000000** . **10101000** . **0000** *0010* . *11001000* = *192.168.2.200*/**20**

Again, since these *hosts* share the same **network prefix**, they are in the same subnet and can communicate directly with each other.

Comment: For No.2 the /20 mask (255.255.240.0) addresses in the range 192.168.0.1 - 192.168.15.254 form one subnet,

But here we want to communicate directly to 192.168.2.x which ISN'T in the same subnet because the subnet stops at 192.168.15.254. Right?

Also 192.168.2.x can't communicate with 192.168.1.1 gateway because it's not in the same subnet. Right?

Comment: ... well I thought the concept of subnet is a bit vague to you... I'll update the answer. Takes a bit, tho', so please be patient :-) And yes, as long as it's unclear do ask!

Comment: Take your time, I'm not in a hurry. Also I'm not a network guy but I understand the basic principles of those things. 
I just asked Chatgpt and "told me" that 192.168.1.x and 192.168.2.x cant communicate with 20 subnet mask.. but i wanted a more expert "human" opinion.
Thank you for your effort to make it more clear

Comment: @odifis Sorry for the long-a$$ writeup, but trying to clarify the entire concept... hope this helps.

Comment: This was the best dragon fire blow ever. Yes it helps and yes it is exceptionally instructional!! <3

Comment: Glad I could help :-) There's also why we call it a subnet mask in the first place... the 1:s on the most significant bits _mask_ the _subnet_ portion of the address. CIDR notation is a lot easier to grasp, methinks.

Comment: "I just asked Chatgpt and "told me" that 192.168.1.x and 192.168.2.x cant communicate with 20 subnet mask" - this is why you should never ask ChatGPT for facts.

Comment: @GuntramBlohm, I think it "knows" the facts, though, it just can't reason or communicate them properly. I got it to give the explanation and do the proper calculations (correctly), and then say "Therefore, if both IP addresses are within the same /20 network block, then they are in the same subnet. If they are not within the same /20 network block, then they are not in the same subnet.". It wasn't able to read the results of the calculations it showed. Hilarious stuff. It did fall back to assuming a Class C network if the mask wasn't given, so it, too, also appears stuck in the 1990's...

Comment: @Ilkkachu - LOL :-D Eminently evident in some recent SE answers, ain't it? Reminds me of some ppl I've worked with. It's really not a question of how much information or knowledge you have. It's how well you can apply it in practice, make synthesis out of it, use logic to fill out possibly missing info...

Comment: Networking makes sense! Sorta... Bookmarked and I'll refer back in the future. TYVM.

Comment: @ilkkachu ChatGPT, like all other GPTs, should be thought of as a highly advanced auto-complete. You know when you press the auto-complete button on your phone and it sometimes makes a sentence? GPT is like that, but way more accurate, in that it almost always produces complete sentences, and sometimes, those sentences are even true.

Answer (score 2):

> can 192.168.2.x network use the 192.168.1.1 gateway because of the 20 mask?

Yes, because they are **not** separate networks – both addresses are within the same 192.168.0.0/20 network.

You're too used to thinking of 192.168.Y.x "always" being separate networks, but that is *only* true for the typical /24 prefix length (255.255.255.0 subnet mask) – which is not the case in your network here; your subnet mask covers 1.x and 2.x (and all the way from 0.x to 15.x), therefore they're in the same network.

<sup>1</sup> (Many operating systems will accept an out-of-subnet gateway address too – what really matters is that the gateway must be "physically" on the same broadcast domain. So if you had, for example, two /24's sharing the same Ethernet, devices in one /24 could use the gateway address of the other /24, although that's not recommended and depends on the OS.)

> is this practice relliable

It is reliable and is exactly how subnetting is done in the first place. (I.e. you're just using the exact same mechanism that normally gives you /24's out of the original 192.168.0.0/16 range.)

The only requirement is that all devices in a subnet need to *agree* on the subnet mask. If the subnet is /20 but someone accidentally configures a device as /24 out of habit, the mismatch will cause problems for that device (though it'll still kind of work, most of the time). It's a good idea to automate configuration through DHCP when possible.

> or it is mandatory every "subnet" to have its own gateway regardless of the subnet mask?

In your network, 192.168.1.x and 192.168.2.x are **not** subnets anymore; the entire /20 is **one** large subnet. That's literally what the subnet mask defines.

So, technically yes, every subnet *should*<sup>1</sup> have its own gateway, but that is not relevant here because you only have one subnet anyway.

> But here we want to communicate directly to 192.168.2.x which ISN'T in the same subnet because the subnet stops at 192.168.15.254. Right?

It very much *is* in the same subnet. These are decimal numbers, and 0 < 2 < 15. So if the subnet starts at 0.0 and ends at 15.25**5** (not 254!), then all of the 2.x addresses are within the range – as are all 7.x addresses, all 10.x addresses, and so on.

Answer (score 0):

I commend the answer of @Perigrino69. Here are two points which might have a bearing on your problem :

1. /20 is a large mask. Normally one uses a smaller mask to reduce the amount of broadcast traffic, which might cause performance problems. With a layer-3 switch performing the routing, splitting into multiple subnets and VLANs has no appreciable performance penalty.
2. There is a feature called *proxy ARP* which is enabled by default on some routers and access points. If, in your scenario, a device running proxy ARP has an address 192.168.1.x/24, it will respond to ARP requests for any 192.168.1.x address with its own MAC address. If it responds faster than the real owner of the address, the real owner becomes unreachable. I experienced this problem on a /20 subnet in a remote site from an unknown device which took out all the PCs but not the servers (they were in a different /24 range).

Comment: On the one hand, OP's post does have the vibes of "IT team putting literally everything in a single subnet", but on the other hand, it could be that they just have the same ~30 hosts in that subnet and just like the flexibility of numbering (i.e. assigning 1.x for one type of devices, 2.x for another, etc), in which case it doesn't really matter whether the prefix is shorter or longer, the amount of broadcasts is still the same. (Not that broadcasts have nearly as much of an impact on switched Ethernet as they did on shared-medium, anyway...)

Comment: Well their 1.x range was full with the company's computers, so they moved all the warehouse equipment to 2.x rage (RF terminals, P2L system etc.)