# Determine which IP address will be used for default route in Powershell

Tags: windows, powershell, routing, ipv6, network-interface

There could be multiple addresses of one Network Interface Card in Windows, such as global unicast IPv6 addresses assigned via DHCPv6, SLAAC, temporary IPv6 or manually, etc. At the same time, there could be multiple Network Interface Cards connected to Internet, and these Network Interface Cards may all have multiple valid global unicast IPv6 addresses.

How to determine which address of which Network Interface Card will be used for default route **without truly issuing an Internet connection**?

Comment: Gateways have to be configured. The info is in the adapter settings whether you open an internet connection or not. There can be multiple gateways to different networks, but usually only one default gateway. That's where traffic that doesn't fit other forwarding rules is sent. IPv4 default gateway is `0.0.0.0/0`, IPv6 default gateway is `::/0`. If the default gateway is 192.168.1.1, the adapter used to forward the traffic is the one whose IP is in the 192.168.0.0/16 range. Here's how to get it in PS:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13869182/how-to-get-the-default-gateway-from-powershell

Comment: @Peregrino69 But what if there're multiple `192.168.0.0/16` addresses assigned to that NIC, just like all manually assigned global anycast IPv6 addresses of the same NIC all have the same (usually 64 bits) prefix

Comment: The gateway is usually the IP of the router that is connected to the network card. The above link by @Peregrino69 shows how to query it with PowerShell.

Comment: A physical interface can only have one IP interface in a subnet. If your NIC has IP 192.168.0.100/24, you cannot give it another IP 192.168.0.101/24. You can't give it IP 192.168.1.101/23 either because /24 is a subnet of /23. So the IP interface used to send traffic to default GW is the one whose IP is in the same subnet with the gateway. The subnet you've configured in the gateway itself doesn't matter, only the subnets configured on your NIC.

Comment: @Peregrino69 Yeah it's true that a NIC can't have more than one IPv4 address, I've tested by issuing `New-NetIPAddress -InterfaceAlias "Wi-Fi" -IPAddress "192.168.0.123" -PolicyStore ActiveStore -PrefixLength 16` resulting in the previous existing IPv4 address overrided. But a NIC can have many manually assigned global unicast IPv6 address

Comment: It can have multiple IPv4 addresses too, just not with the same network prefix, i.e. in the same subnet :-) IPv6 is still a bit hazy to me in this context (multiple IPs etc.), I've not needed it in my work yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For PowerShell (at least the built-in PowerShell 5) you have `Find-NetRoute`. You do have to specify the destination you want to determine a route for, and optionally also the source address – the tool does not assume that a *default* route will be the only kind of route.

The trick used by `ip route get` on Linux is to create an actual UDP datagram socket, bind it to the specified destination, and read out the socket state after the kernel has made its decisions. This works without having to send any packets.

Comment: Thanks! Seems the cmdlet `Find-NetRoute` is what I'm looking for, but its executing result is wrong under my condition, maybe I could send an issue to Powershell. I manually assigned a global anycast IPv6 address, then set all other global anycast IPv6 addresses' `SkipAsSource` to `$True`, resulting in all the outgoing IPv6 connections toward Internet always send from the IPv6 address I manually assigned, but the executing result of `Find-NetRoute -RemoteIPAddress 2606:4700:4700::1111` shows the DHCPv6 address.

Answer (score 0):

The Default Gateway must be configured. Since it's in the driver's settings, it can be queried without having an active internet connection. If the IP address is static, it can be queried even without any network connection.

The IP interface used to forward traffic to the default gateway is the one whose IP address is in the same subnet. IPv4 specifies DGW as `0.0.0.0/0`, IPv6 `::0`.

Multiple DGWs can be configured, but if done, they need to be prioritized using metric, weight or similar concept. Multiple DGWs with the same priority will cause connectivity problems.

---

Assume this multi-homed system:

```
+-----------------------+
|  eth0 192.168.0.100/24|--
|                       |
|  eth1 192.168.1.100/24|--
|                       |
|  eth2 192.168.2.100/24|--
+-----------------------+
```

Default Gateway is 192.168.2.254. The IP interface used to forward to DGW is 192.168.2.100/24, because it's in the same IP range with 192.168.2.254.

Now assume this single-homed system with multiple IP interfaces on a single NIC:

```
+-----------------------+
|  eth0 192.168.0.100/24|
|                       |
|  eth1 192.168.1.100/24|--
|                       |
|  eth2 192.168.2.100/24|
+-----------------------+
```

Default Gateway is 192.168.2.254. The IP interface used to forward to DGW is again 192.168.2.100/24, because it's in the same IP range with 192.168.2.254.

A physical interface can only have one IP interface into a given IP address range. If the interface has IP 192.168.0.100/24:

- it cannot have another IP interface in the range 192.168.0.0-255 because it already has one interface on this range
- it cannot have another IP interface 192.168.1.100/23, because /23 IP address range is 192.168.0.0-.1.255, and it already has one interface in that range.
- it cannot have another IP interface 192.168.1.200/25, because 192.168.1.200 is within the /24 IP range
- it can have any other IP interface that's outside of the /24 IP range

In PowerShell the DGW can be queried multiple ways, at least using [Get-NetIPConfiguration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/nettcpip/get-netipconfiguration?view=windowsserver2022-ps), [Get-NetRoute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/nettcpip/get-netroute?view=windowsserver2022-ps) and [Get-WmiObject](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-wmiobject?view=powershell-5.1). Further info and examples can be found in [this Stack Overflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13869182/how-to-get-the-default-gateway-from-powershell) and the previous Microsoft links.

Overview on subnets and CIDR network prefixes is available in my answer [here](https://superuser.com/a/1769952/330527), and more detailed info can be found in the internet.